# default path in a singularity container

Tags: recipe, singularity-container

I'm very new to the container space and after following some tutorials I'm trying to get my own singularity container up and running.

My recipe is as follows:

```
BootStrap: debootstrap
OSVersion: trusty
MirrorURL: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

%post
    #install strelka2.9.2 - these commands get run during the container build stage
    apt-get -y --force-yes install wget bzip2 python-dev
    wget https://github.com/Illumina/strelka/releases/download/v2.9.2/strelka-2.9.2.centos6_x86_64.tar.bz2
    tar xvjf strelka-2.9.2.centos6_x86_64.tar.bz2

%environment
    #What to put here to find the strelka-2.9.2.centos6_x86_64/bin/ folder?
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add the downloaded binary to the executable path.   I expected the downloaded files in the post section to show up in the /home/ or similar inside the container, but I can't seem to find them when I shell in with `singularity shell myImage.simg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the PATH used in the container is the PATH of the environment you run it from. An easy way to ensure the path is what you want is set: `PATH=/path/to/strelka/bin:$PATH` under `%environment`.

A simple definition file you can you to quickly play around with:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: debian:buster-slim

%environment
    PATH=/some/weird/path/bin:$PATH

%runscript
    echo "PATH is: $PATH"
```